# Custom Taxonomy From Database

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

i want to create one site with Wordpress and for that i have some weird requirement. i wants the site like, when admin write any post at that time he have to select then `product` for that page. `(i.e Mobile or Tab or PC etc..)` and also have to select Brand for that product. like if admin has select the `Mobile` then there should be an option available for brand for that product. `(i had create custom menu for that and save product and brand value in my custom table. Relationship is like : brands -> hasmany -> product)`. now i want to just use this table data in right bar of admin post page. i had google about it and i found the `Custom Taxonomy` concept for that but i think it won't help me because in that, admin can create any item from post page (in my case, i haven't allow it) and another one, most important for me, is if i use the `Custom Taxonomy` then i don't think that it can maintain the relationship like if product is `Mobile` then brand `Levi's` should not be in the list.

Can any one help me please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If custom taxonomy makes sense to you as approach to organization of data, but not as interface workflow then you should consider building custom interface for it.

Some frameworks out there can work with native taxonomies, but provide alternate interfaces for them. So you might even find something fitting already done.

The more low key approach I can think of would be to customize permissions to allow use of existing terms, but prohibit creation of new ones by users doing data entry. You can customize permissions for specific taxonomy when you register it or customize from the user role.